# How to do a recursive 'git checkout'?

Tags: git

I have a parent directory and inside that directory there are multiple sub-directories which contain .git directories consisting of objects.

How do I run 'git checkout -f .' recursively for each sub-directory?

Answer (score 2):

Can use the following command inside parent directory

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print -exec git -C {} checkout -f \;
```

`maxdepth 1` - looks only for subdirectories 
`type d` - looks only for directory type

Answer (score 0):

git doesn't natively support what you described.

However, a git repository *can* include another repository using [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). Once you have setup your submodules, one git clone/checkout will update those submodules too.

To add submodules, in your top-level git repository:

```
git submodule add <submodule git repo>
```

Git submodules are managed through a .gitmodules file (in plain-text format), which is committed to your top-level git repository.